# Preparing automatic repair

Tags: windows-8, hp-pavilion

My windows 8 Pavillion 13 HP computer has gone into a preparing automatic repair. After a few moments, it then goes into a black screen of death. I have tried a hard reset, taking the battery out, etc. It will not let me go into the BIOS menu. Due to this, I cannot re-install the OS.

It has an AMD A8, a spinning hard drive, it has 500 gigs of space.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: See this page>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1/how-to-fix-the-automatic-repair-loop-in-windows-81/bfc92bc7-031f-45d4-b623-bcb4847d32fd

Comment: If you could not boot into Safe Mode, I consider that you could try to use a Media installation to repair. DVD or USB with Windows 8 ISO. Then go into BIOS to set boot order. Then click repair the system option.